# ошибка react + typescript + react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Текст ошибки:
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps | Readonly): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

package.json:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У роутера в качестве вложенного должен быть только один элемент, а у вас - два. Оберните их в div.

```
<Router>
  <div>
   <NavBar/>
   <div>
   </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Но вообще в роутере по хорошему ничего кроме роутов быть не должно. Элементы расположенные по путям должны возвращать общий шаблон страницы, который подразумевает отрисовку заголовка, футера, и уже всех своих детей, разных для каждого роута детей. что то вроде

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Router>
        <Route path="/ххх/" element={<RootView/>} />
         <Route path="yyy" element={<LoginScreen/>} />
    </Router>
  </Routes>
<BrowserRoute>
```

LoginScreen:

```
<CommonPage>     вот тут рисуется заголовок и меню боковое и футер
   <LoginForm/>   
   <RegistrationForm/>
</CommonPage>
```

RootView:

```
<CommonPage>     
   <Chart/>   
   <UserDetails/>
</CommonPage>
```

CommonPage:

```
class CommonPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <NavBar/>
      <div>Children ({this.props.children.length}):</div>
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```